# How to filter CloudWatch event by event id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

How to filter cloudwatch events based on the event id eg: DMS-EVENT-0078, DMS-EVENT-0082
we are looking at the cloudwatch event messages but not able to see the event-id
we are planning to use a lambda to filter only few event-id and create alarms accordingly

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Events.html

Thank you
your Support is Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Database Migration Service notification events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Events.html) are **separate** from CloudWatch (CW) Events. You can't use them from CW Events rules.

CW Events support only `AWS API Call via CloudTrail` events for DMS.

Thus you can setup SNS for the DMS notifications, which in turn will invoke your lambda function. The lambda function can filter or process the events of interest to you.